# How to install OS to Mac Air with a different Apple ID

Tags: macos

I got a Mac Air from friend and the Mac OS is 10.7(Lion). I try to delete friend's data but unfortunately I deleted the whole disk and now there is no Mac OS in this Air. There is always only a folder with question mark in a white background after starting up this Air. My question is how to install any Mac OS to this Air now?

I try to Restore to the manufacture and go to page Reinstall Mac OS X. I enter my Apple ID and password and it only shows OS Lion for download. But when I click download, it says this OS is temporarily unavailable in AppStore. It seems I have to download and install Mavericks (it's free.) But I need a proper Apple ID - the one that has been used with the computer to install App Store software, which should be my friend's Apple ID. May I use my Apple ID to install Mavericks to this Air? Is there any other way to install Mavericks or Lion to this Air? Thanks.

Comment: Try superuser.com or apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Yes, download the ISO(image) of the latest Mavericks, write it to DVD or build an USB Boot install disk with some free tools available online.

After boot from USB/DVD and install, you will have a fresh install.

Comment: Where to download the ISO file? May I make the DVD from the dmg file?

Comment: see [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128319/official-way-to-obtain-an-os-x-iso-file)